# How can I use sed/awk/perl to replace a matched pattern with an equivalent number of dashes?

Tags: regex, sed, scripting, escaping, ksh

I would like to search for all occurrences of a pattern in a file and replace the matches with an equivalent number of padding such as spaces or dashes. It is important to note that **I DO NOT WANT TO ALTER THE FILE!** I would like like to print the result as standard output. This is why I prefer using sed. The output should be the same length as the file since I would like to replace each pattern found by the regex with the length of that pattern in dashes.
Example: Say the file contains the following:

```
data | more data | "to be dashed"
```

Desired Output:

```
data | more data | --------------
```

I currently have some thing like this:

```
sed -e 's/["][^"]*["]/-/g' file
```

which results in:

```
data | more data | -
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the edits, it looks much more readable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(".*?")/ "-" x length($1) /ge' <<END
data | more data | "to be dashed"
data | "more data" | "multi words " "to be dashed"
END
```

```
data | more data | --------------
data | ----------- | -------------- --------------
```

Since you need to find the string length of the matched text, you need to run the substitution part of `s///` through a round of evaluation, hence the `e` flag.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ FS = "" }{ while (match($0, /^(.*)(["][^"]*["])(.*)$/, a)){ gsub(/./, "-", a[2]); $0 = a[1] a[2] a[3]; } } 1' file
```

Examples:

```
$ echo 'data | more data | "to be dashed"' | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS = "" }{ while (match($0, /^(.*)(["][^"]*["])(.*)$/, a)){ gsub(/./, "-", a[2]); $0 = a[1] a[2] a[3]; } } 1'
data | more data | --------------

$ echo 'data | more data | "to be dashed" x "1234"' | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS = "" }{ while (match($0, /^(.*)(["][^"]*["])(.*)$/, a)){ gsub(/./, "-", a[2]); $0 = a[1] a[2] a[3]; } } 1'
data | more data | -------------- x ------
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. I'm not sure what the `FS=""` is for, though. Is it just so no restructuring of the line by fields will occur when `$0` is rebuilt?

Comment: @ooga It's pretty unnecessary but I just don't want FS to get in the way just in case - whatever effect it may give.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed -r '
    :loop
      h                            # copy pattspace to holdspace
      s/(.*)("[^"]+")(.*)/\1\n\3/  # replace quoted field with newline
      T                            # if no replacement occurred, start next cycle
      x                            # exchange pattspace and holdspace
      s/.*("[^"]+").*/\1/          # isolate quoted field
      s/./-/g                      # change all chars to dashes
      G                            # append newline and holdspace to pattspace
      s/(-*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1\3/   # reorder fields using newlines
      t loop                       # repeat (must be conditional for T to work)
' file
```

OSX/BSD may not have the T command (jump to label (or next cycle) if substitution has not been made since last line read or last conditional jump). In that case, replace `T` with:

```
t keeplooping      # branch over b if substitution occurred
b                  # unconditional branch to next cycle
:keeplooping
```

Comment: oddly This printed my file as is, and did not make any substitutions..
did this work on your machine?

Comment: ooga was using asterisks, not quotes. Answer edited.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. For some reason I though it was asterisks?! I've edited it again to fix the comments to match.